# installing yarn "works" but yarn command is not found

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, yarnpkg, nvm

I asked a question previously, but i no longer get that error and simply installing yarn through `npm install yarn` or `npm install -g yarn` or `npm install --global yarn` seems to go through and says this `changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 334ms` .
And when I type `yarn` it just says `zsh: command not found: yarn` so i have no clue why.
I have even tried to use `nvm` but that does nothing, and when I follow the install guide, it seems to "work" then once i close terminal, its gone. This is pretty frustrating because I dont really know how this works and I dont want to ruin anything on my computer either, also with using `sudo` and what not. Im on an m1 mac if that affects anything. Im really just so confused on this.

Answer (score 0):

use "npm install --global yarn" command.

Answer (score -1):

Install yarn globally

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Check the version. If you get version, everything is ok

```
yarn --version
1.22.19
```

If you **DO NOT** get version

```
npm config get prefix
```

You get path like this

```
\Your_User_Name\Path\npm
```

Add this **path** to your system environments

**If the above method is not work properly, so follow this way**

```
mkdir react
cd \Your_User_Name\Path\react
yarn create vite 
( name: react, framework: react, version: react)
cd react
yarn (i.e. install yarn)
code . (open VSC)
yarn preview
yarn dev
```